# I am trying to make a simple dash for my character but there is an issue (i use unity's new input system)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically i am trying to do a code that makes "dashing" bool, true for 0.2 sec when pressed. but i cannot call the  IEnumerator dash(). (i use unity's new input system)

```
public void dash(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.performed)
            StartCoroutine("dash");
    }

    
    IEnumerator dash()
    {
        dashing = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        dashing = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> StartCoroutine("dash");

this is not the correct way to call a coroutine, it should do something like this:

```
StartCoroutine(dash());
```

Or this:

```
IEnumerator coroutine = dash();
StartCoroutine(coroutine);
```

Hope this helps!